# Click event for button in loop C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, buttonclick

I have couple buttons which im putting in wrapPanel in loop:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < wrapWidthItems; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < wrapHeightItems; j++)
            {
                Button bnt = new Button();
                bnt.Width = 50;
                bnt.Height = 50;
                bnt.Content = "Button" + i + j;
                bnt.Name = "Button" + i + j;
bnt.Click += method here ?
                wrapPanelCategoryButtons.Children.Add(bnt);
            }
        }
```

I want to know which button was clicked and do something different for each of them. For example ill have method

```
private void buttonClicked(Button b)
```

where ill send clicked button, check type, name or id of that and then do something.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your loop:

```
bnt.Click += (source, e) =>
{
    //type the method's code here, using bnt to reference the button 
};
```

Lambda expressions allow you to embed anonymous methods in your code so that you can access local method variables. You can read more about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: I highly recommend not using anonymous methods for event handlers unless you keep a named reference to the method somewhere. Otherwise, you have no way of removing the event(other than using reflection to remove *all* the handlers from the event).

Comment: @rossisdead I respectfully disagree; removing an event is, in my experience, a very rare requirement, and on the rare chance that you do need to remove it, you can always change a boolean value to simply stop/not execute the loop. I don't see the logic of discarding the immense benefits of anonymous methods for the rare requirement of removing them, which can be accomplished via alternative means either way.

Comment: @Daniel: I'll respectfully disagree in return :) lol. I agree that it's a non-issue when it's used in a scenario where there's no need for removing the event listener. But I think in a best practices scenario you should always make it possible to clean up event handlers to prevent memory leaks(not as much of an issue with WPF if all the control events use weak handlers). WPF can also be a bit of a memory/performance hog, so using a single handler reference for all the buttons could also potentially be better than creating a new handler for each button.

Comment: One other note, if you've ever used the WPF Toolkit's charting controls, they make liberal use of anonymous functions for event handlers, but also leak memory horribly due to improper cleanup :/

Answer (score 3):

All methods you hook up to an event have an argument `sender`, it is the object, that triggered the event. So in your case sender the Button object that was clicked. You can just cast it like this:

```
void button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button buttonThatWasClicked = (Button)sender;
    // your code here e.g. call your method buttonClicked(buttonThatWasClicked);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for both responses - both works. There is full code maybe someone else could need that in future

```
    for (int i = 0; i < wrapWidthItems; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < wrapHeightItems; j++)
        {
            Button bnt = new Button();
            bnt.Width = 50;
            bnt.Height = 50;
            bnt.Content = "Button" + i + j;
            bnt.Name = "Button" + i + j;
            bnt.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(bnt_Click);
           /* bnt.Click += (source, e) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Button pressed" + bnt.Name);
            };*/
            wrapPanelCategoryButtons.Children.Add(bnt);
        }
    }

}

void bnt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Button buttonThatWasClicked = (Button)sender;
    MessageBox.Show("Button pressed " + buttonThatWasClicked.Name);

}
```

By the way I'd like to know if that possible to (using wrapPanel) move buttons into another location ? I mean when i will click and drag button will be able to do that in wrappanel?

Comment: Definitely somebody is in need of it today, I am glad for this